# Regex: Possible to simplify this?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this JavaScript Regex: `/(\.abc$|^abc$|abc\.def$)/i`.  I feel like this is extremely redundant and it can be simplified.  Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:
- It needs to match `.abc` only at the end or only `abc` or only `abc.def`

Edit: I realized I could place `$` at the end of the parenthesis and it could become `/(\.abc|^abc|abc\.def)$/i`.  However, this still seems redundant

Comment: It doesn't seem redundant.

Comment: Huh, figured that there could be a way to use `abc` once since they all contain that.

Comment: According to your own regex and rules `^abc(?:\.def)?$|\.abc$`

Comment: An alternative: `(?:\.|^)?abc(?:\.def)?$`. However your original regex is more efficient than according to regex101.

Comment: The `/(\.abc|^abc|abc\.def)$/i` is all you can do. Of course, you may [use a variable for a block](). But it is already a dupe then. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-use-a-variable-in-a-regular-expression).

Answer (score 0):

You can only combine two of the options at a time because of the fork implied by `.abc.def` not matching at the end.

SO each case combines two and adds the remaining option:

```
(^abc(\.def)?|\.abc)$

((^|\.)abc|^abc\.def)$
```